# Disable logging in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, monolog

Is there any global configuration option to disable all logging?

I don't just mean disabling the logging of errors. I mean actually disabling writing to the file when Log:: is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to write to a log file you can simply comment out the following line in file `start/global.php`

```
//Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');
```

From this point on, your log file will never be updated.