# How to disable Laravel 5 log file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My **Laravel 5** website is working in a shared host with 1 GB disk space. But now I have about 100 MB log file. How I can **disable log file** in **Laravel 5** ?

Comment: maybe interesting? duplicate? [Is there any global configuration option to disable all logging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321898/disable-logging-in-laravel)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to completely disable logging you'll need to overwrite the default log handlers that are set by Laravel. You can easily do this with

```
$nullLogger = new NullHandler();
\Log::getMonolog()->setHandlers(array($nullLogger));
```

You need to call as early as possible, before request is processed, e.g. you could do that in your **bootstrap/app.php**:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
  $nullLogger = new \Monolog\Handler\NullHandler();
  $monolog->setHandlers(array($nullLogger));
});

return $app;
```

Comment: Is there no config-only solution?

Answer (score 12):

I know that this a bit old, but:

In config/logging.php:
In `channels` section add these:

```
'none' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\NullHandler::class,
],
```

Then update your .env file to use this logger:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=none
```

And everything should work just fine.

Comment: Just a note, full class name of `NullHandler` is `\Monolog\Handler\NullHandler`

Comment: does it make a difference if i just use  NullHandler::class,  or full  \Monolog\Handler\NullHandler  what releavence is it ?

Comment: @user3548161 no

Comment: I'm on Laravel 5.8.38. It does make a difference. When I used `NullHandler` without the fully qualified class name, it didn't work. It still created `laravel.log`, which logged an additional exception, without rendering it in Whoops: `Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): NullHandler must be an instance of Monolog\\Handler\\HandlerInterface at <snip>/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:328`. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin just use "use" statement to reference class at the top. Its not laravel-related stuff

Comment: @TymurValiiev Doh, you're right. I knew to look for it, but I still overlooked that the other handlers were referenced via a `use` statement at the top. I should have done the same for `NullHandler`. I'll keep my comment and edit in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 10):

If your log is very large then either you are logging a lot or your application is throwing a lot of errors. You should first examine the log and see if you can reduce data being written.

You can also switch to daily logging and then have a job to delete old log files.

The next thing to do would be to update your logging configuration to daily instead of the default single in `config/app.php`

Laravel will handle rotating the file daily and deleting old log files after 5 days, or the value of the `app.max_log_files` if you need more kept.

Answer (score 1):

#### Maximum Daily Log Files

When using the daily log mode, Laravel will only retain `five days` of log files by default. If you want to adjust the number of retained files, you may add a `log_max_files` configuration value to your  `app` configuration file:

#### config >> app.php

```
'log_max_files' => 30
```

For more : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors

Comment: What does 30 mean? 30 mega bytes?

Comment: No @Vahid2015, it means 30 files in a month

Answer (score 0):

for me, the folder 'tmp' in wamp was growing up 15 giga!!
after some research I found out that the reason was the xdebug extension
I simply adjut it not to send debug info, from `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
```

Answer (score -3):

You May disable the writing action Log:: is called by commenting the follow line:

```
Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');
```

in `start/global.php`

But first, you should find out why your log file is that big?
Second, having some kind of archive function to your file will help as well. Maybe twice a day.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: My site is under DDos attack, and the log file (50GB) was getting full, which caused my server to stop working. By stopping the writing of this file I was able to concentrate on the solution.

Answer (score -14):

Yes definitively you need to edit core laravel file in order not to save log file ..

go to vendor->laravel->framework->src->Illuminate->Log->Writer.php
and then comment out all the code within function __call like below.

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    // if (in_array($method, $this->levels))
    // {
    //  call_user_func_array(array($this, 'fireLogEvent'), array_merge(array($method), $parameters));

    //  $method = 'add'.ucfirst($method);

    //  return $this->callMonolog($method, $parameters);
    // }

    // throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
}
```

You log will never be save.

Comment: Editing vendor files is very bad idea. Next composer update/install will loose all your modifications.

Comment: This is a terrible suggestion for the reasons stated in the first comment.