# A problem with automatically increasing the file size in a project laravel

Tags: laravel, file

I have a problem with a file named
storage\logs\laravel.log
From LARAVEL Project Files
The strange thing is that this file is automatically increased in size every day, so I needed to delete it so that the site would not stop working
Do you have a solution to this problem how to stop this file from working automatically
So that the site does not stop because there is no free space

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652933/how-to-disable-laravel-5-log-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change logging driver to `daily`. This will create new log file daily, with date in file name.

in `config/logging.php`

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'daily'),

'channels' => [
    ....

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'days' => 14,
    ],
    ....
```

Set the number days that you want log files to keep. After that the old log files will be deleted automatically.

For more information [Check the Laravel documentation for Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging).

Comment: thank you
I will try this solution right away
I was not aware of the mission of this file
Thanks again