# Error on php artisan migrate, Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-7

I try to do `php artisan migrate` , but I get an error.

I check the database,user name, password, I tried with sudo, but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error: laravel.log could not be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)

Comment: The group is already in www-data ,also I try to give permission 775, but the same.

Comment: Does your app work outside migration commands?

Comment: If it does it's strange. Disable the logging engine each time you run the migrations and try again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26325499/8555937

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

First thing: (to access laravel.log)

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Second one:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-pgsql
```